# Add multiple condition to group by and having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

3I have the following query

```
SELECT deal_id, max(test_value) - min(test_value) AS deviation
  FROM  table
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -4, Getdate())
  and test_alias='BOND_P' 
  group by deal_id
  having (max(test_value) - min(test_value)) BETWEEN 1.79 AND 4.5
```

and

```
     SELECT deal_id, max(test_value) - min(test_value) AS deviation
  FROM  ems.cdotests
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -3, Getdate())
  and test_alias='CAA/CCC' 
  group by deal_id
  having (max(test_value) - min(test_value)) BETWEEN 2.79 AND 2
```

I need to combine the this query so that i can get the output as the

```
1: result set of query 1 intersected with result set of query 2
2: result set of query 1 unioned with result set of query 2
```

'Intersect' or 'Union' will depend upon the parameter passed to the stored procedure

Ps Note: The run date criteria between the two query can be different 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What you mean and/or result? You need to run both queries or any one query based on condition?

Comment: i need to run one query 'and' or 'or based on my bit flag which is passed as a parameter to stored proc

Comment: You want result as single output or two values for and condition?

Comment: Perhaps sample data and desired results.  As is, it's very difficult to understand the scope of the question...

Comment: are you saying you want 1: query1 `inner join` query2 and 2: query1 `UNION` query2?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't do:   IF Bit_Flag = 0 SELECT (Query0) ELSE SELECT (Query1)?

Comment: yes i want to somehting inline with query1 inner join query2 and 2: query1 UNION query2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF @myBitParameter = 0
  SELECT deal_id, max(test_value) - min(test_value) AS deviation
  FROM  [table]
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -4, Getdate())
  and test_alias='BOND_P' 
  group by deal_id
  having (max(test_value) - min(test_value)) BETWEEN 1.79 AND 4.5 

  UNION ALL --or UNION, if you don't want duplicates

  SELECT deal_id, max(test_value) - min(test_value) AS deviation
  FROM  ems.cdotests
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -3, Getdate())
  and test_alias='CAA/CCC' 
  group by deal_id
  having (max(test_value) - min(test_value)) BETWEEN 2.79 AND 2

ELSE
  SELECT deal_id, max(test_value) - min(test_value) AS deviation
  FROM  [table]
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -4, Getdate())
  and test_alias='BOND_P' 
  group by deal_id
  having (max(test_value) - min(test_value)) BETWEEN 1.79 AND 4.5 

  INTERSECT

  SELECT deal_id, max(test_value) - min(test_value) AS deviation
  FROM  ems.cdotests
  WHERE run_date >= Dateadd(month, -3, Getdate())
  and test_alias='CAA/CCC' 
  group by deal_id
  having (max(test_value) - min(test_value)) BETWEEN 2.79 AND 2
```

I feel like there should be a way to do this cleaner with CTE's, but don't have time to fool with it any more.  Someone feel free to clean this up or make a better answer out of it.

Comment: Note too that the `UNION ALL` will give you duplicates.  If you want distinct values, just use `UNION`